# How to add number of weeks to Current Time (Now) in C or C++?

Tags: c++, boost

How to add number of weeks to Current Date in C or C++ ?

For the months part , i.e. adding months to current date by using "difftime" function in "ctime.h". For weeks it is not so trivial and i am looking for  solution with less LOC.

Here this code finds the difference between the current time and 01-Jan of same year.    I used the logic similar to this to do the task of adding x months to current time.

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, struct tm, difftime, time, mktime */

int main ()
{
  time_t now;
  struct tm newyear;
  double seconds;

  time(&now);  /* get current time; same as: now = time(NULL)  */

  newyear = *localtime(&now);

  newyear.tm_hour = 0; newyear.tm_min = 0; newyear.tm_sec = 0;
  newyear.tm_mon = 0;  newyear.tm_mday = 1;

  seconds = difftime(now,mktime(&newyear));

  printf ("%.f seconds since new year in the current timezone.\n", seconds);

  return 0;
}
```

where tm_mon will be set according to the number of months i am looking for( i have taken care year shifting also) .
I cannot use the tm_wday to do the same stuff.

Comment: You should precise what you mean by "Current Date". There are various ways to store a date in c++.

Comment: You've included the `C++-CLI` tag, which would be *very* different to do this using the .Net libary vs. C libraries.

Comment: Current Date i mean "Now" .  I think i need to remove c++-cli tag , i am looking for solution in c or c++ only.

Comment: `time_t`, `std::chrono::time_point`, `boost::gregorian::date`, `System::DateTime`? How do you want us to guess which one you are using... ?

Comment: To do the "months" part i have used the time_t .

Comment: You should show us what you did for "months" and explain why it does not work for weeks. Your question is currently totally unclear.

Comment: Updated the description with the logic.

Answer (score 2):

For C++11 (which introduced `<chrono>` header):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto nextWeek = now + std::chrono::hours(24*7);
std::time_t nextWeek_time_t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(nextWeek);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Jan Henke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36772819/576911) is correct and I've upvoted it. But I wanted to add that it is best practice to let `<chrono>` do all unit conversions for you.  In this case we don't have the unit `weeks`.  But we can easily build one.

Start with creating a unit `days`:

```
using days = std::chrono::duration
    <int, std::ratio_multiply<std::ratio<24>, std::chrono::hours::period>>;
```

This says:

> There are 24 hours in a day.

Now you are ready to build `weeks`:

```
using weeks = std::chrono::duration
    <int, std::ratio_multiply<std::ratio<7>, days::period>>;
```

> There are 7 days in a week.

Now it is very simple to use `weeks` (and `days`) as you would any other `<chrono>` unit:

```
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto nextWeek = now + weeks{1};
```

---

If you want to do something such as compute the number of full weeks that have elapsed since the start of the year in the local time zone, you could use this [free, open source C++11/14 timezone library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) which leverages the `<chrono>` library.

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    // Get current timezone
    auto zone = current_zone();
    // Get current system time
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    // Find the current year in the current timezone
    auto local_now = zone->to_local(now);
    auto y = year_month_day{floor<days>(local_now)}.year();
    // Find the system time of the start of the local year
    auto newyear = zone->to_sys(local_days{y/jan/1});
    // Get the difference between these two system times, truncated to weeks
    auto diff_weeks = floor<weeks>(now - newyear);
    std::cout << diff_weeks.count() << '\n';
}
```

which just output for me:

```
15
```

If you aren't concerned about taking the local timezone into account, you can do this quite a bit more simply by just computing everything in UTC with:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    // Get current system time
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    // Find the current year
    auto y = year_month_day{floor<days>(now)}.year();
    // Find the time of the start of the year
    sys_days newyear = y/jan/1;
    // Get the difference between these two system times, truncated to weeks
    auto diff_weeks = floor<weeks>(now - newyear);
    std::cout << diff_weeks.count() << '\n';
}
```

which also just output:

```
15
```